# Insertion sort program in python

Tags: python, insertion-sort, insertion

I implemented insertion sort and it worked. But while using a different condition I am confused.  I feel should also work correctly but its not working

```
def insertion(arr):
    for i  in  range(1,len(arr)):
        value = arr[i]
        j=i-1
        while j>=0 and value<arr[j]:
            arr[j+1]=arr[j]
            j=j-1
        arr[j+1]= value

arr = [2,4,1,8 ,3,6]
new = insertion(arr)
print("Sorted array by selection sort:")
for i in range(len(arr)):
    print(arr[i])
```

This code works perfectly. But I am confused in the while loop.
The while loop goes like this: `while j>=0 and value<arr[j]:` 
here **value<arr[j]** is used. Why can't I use **arr[i]<arr[j]** instead?
We already set **value = arr[i]**.
How are both these conditions different?

Comment: Because `arr[i]` can change in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using **arr[i]<arr[j]** is not safe, because you're changing the values of arr inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the first assignment within the while loop, the following condition may be true:

```
(j + 1) == i
```

Thus the original value in a[i] may be substituted